# JavaScript console showing a different console output

Tags: javascript

```
const firstLi = document.querySelector('li:first-child');
console.log(firstLi)
```

Every time I save(Command + S), the web console side shows a different output randomly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mEJp.png) The longer one

```
<li class="collective-item>...</li>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGZo3.png) The shorter one

```
li.collective-item
```

How do I edit the setting to show a consistent console output preferably the longer one?
Because I would like to see the code structure(the longer one) not the whole list of methods(the shorter one).

And why does this show a different output randomly on JavaScript web console?

Comment: It sounds like you, or your build system, may be alternating `console.log` with `console.dir`?

Comment: Where do you find that it's alternating console.log with console.dir in build system in VScode/web console?

Comment: Click on the `app.js:30` part to see where it's coming from

Comment: I clicked and looked at it on app.js on Sources. And it still is `console.log(firstLi)` not `console.dir`.

Comment: something in your toolset is probably overriding console.log. Perhaps via devtools or in another .js file, and the difference is in timing and how quickly different parts load

Comment: to get a clue, try `console.log(console.log)` just before the other output.

Comment: Very strange... When I close Sources(clicking `app.js:30`) down and save(Command + S), it still shows a random output mostly the shorter one). But when I clicked `app.js:30` and observe Sources, as if the browser is aware that I'm observing, it shows the longer one. Why is it like that?

Comment: better yet, to be sure, do `const log=console.log; log(log, firstLi);` and see if there is a difference in the `log` output when it does long vs short version.

Comment: Do I always have to insert `const log = console.log; log(log, firstLi);` every time I use `console.log();`?

Still when I use `const log = console.log; log(log, firstLi);`, the random return still shows up without clicking `app.js:31'.